# How can I configure Google Chrome to preview a representation with a custom media type in the browser instead of offering to download it to a file?

Tags: rest, google-chrome, http, browser, media-type

For HTTP resource representations delivered with an unknown-to-the-browser, custom media type, Google Chrome offers to download the representation into a file.

I would like to know how I can configure it to preview the representation in the browser instead of providing a download window for a list of media types of my choosing.

Comment: I don't think that will be possible. If the mediatype is unknown to chrome, how is it supposed to display a representation of a resource other than raw binary as text?

Comment: What is the actual media type? Chrome seems to render content sent with `text/vnd.whatever` (because `text/` suggests human-readable text), but will offer to download `application/vnd.whatever` even if it is sent with `Content-Disposition: inline`. However, Firefox doesn’t render even `text/vnd.whatever`.